# Что делать если проект в Unity удалился

Tags: c#, unity3d

Что делать если проект в Unity удалился
я сохранил проект (CTRL + S), а при открытии все файлы сбросились до стандартных.
В проводнике всё тоже пусто, так сломано уже 2 проекта

в корзине тоже пусто

проги для восстановления удалённых файлов видят эти файлы, но не восстанавливают

использую Unity 2021
[image: Версии Юнити]

Comment: Делать все с нуля, и впредь использовать Git для сохранения.

Comment: Разработчики делятся на 2 типа: которые используют СКВ, и которые будут использовать.

Comment: Не знаю как на счёт текущей IDE, а например PhpStorm Имеет свою локальную историю. И можно восстановить данные даже не имея git или подобное ПО. Так что надо посмотреть, есть ли тут локальная история....... а так.....восстановить только через проги можно, если там пусто - то СЕ ЛЯ ВИ